# Why doesn't braced initialization throw a narrowing error when converting from double to float?

Tags: c++, floating-point, g++, double, narrowing

Two things every C++ tutorial mentions early on:

1. Braced initialization is generally superior when possible, because it will throw an error during a narrowing conversion such as

```
int narrow{1.7}; // error: narrowing conversion of '1.7e+0' from 'double' to 'int'
```

2. You must explicitly declare floats as float literals, otherwise they will default to double literals

```
float some_float{1.7f};
```

However, when working with the g++ compiler on Windows, I've discovered something odd -

```
float narrow{1.7}; // still a float despite no f postfix
double not_narrow{1.7}; // actually a double
```

This code compiles without any errors, and `sizeof(narrow)` returns 4, where `sizeof(not_narrow)` returns 8, as expected.
Hovering over 1.7, VSCode identifies it as a double literal ~=1.699999999999999956, but float has then narrowed it to ~=1.700000048.
I thought it might be simply that 1.7 is both valid as a float and a double, so I tried

```
float narrow{1.699999999999999956};
```

but this produces an identical result.
Why doesn't braced initialization throw an error (warning, diagnostic message, anything) here for narrowing a double literal to a float? Is this g++ specific, or a quirk of C++ in general? I'd love to understand better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A conversion from a floating-point type to a shorter floating-point type is not a narrowing conversion if "the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion is within the range of values that can be represented (even if it cannot be represented exactly)" (C++20 [dcl.init.list]/7.2).

If you think about it, `double{1.7}` and `float{1.7}` are most likely both inexact. But if you write the latter, it's reasonable to assume that you mean it, and there's not much to be gained from prohibiting this.

Comment: In the same vein, it would be silly to prohibit `char ch{5}; short s{-7}; unsigned u{42};` even though all of these literals have type `int`, and passing a non-constant value of type `int` would be erroneous.